# WinRT XAML apps + missing [XmlnsDefinition] attribute

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, xml-namespaces

There is not `[XmlnsDefinition]` attribute in XAML metro style applications, based on WinRT.
How my custom namespace mappings from WPF/SL apps should be migrated to WinRT XAML apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like XmlnsDefinitionAttribute is [missing](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/eb0d6a76-27a3-4a85-8108-6af9200375fa). There is [XmlnsDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xmlnsdefinition.aspx) struct but that is of not much use since there is no way to use it to set custom namespace mappings.

Answer (score 0):

A discussion at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/026baea0-6324-46ee-956a-72dbb4c90ca1/xmlnsdefinition-replacement-in-winrt?prof=required says:

> there is no analogous attribute.
>
> You might be able to provide similar data in a custom
>   IXamlMetadataProvider implementation, but since that is automatically
>   generated for you I'm not sure it can be overridden.